# Building ZXing (Zebra Crossing) Library on Linux

Tags: c++

I'm currently struggling to get started with ZXing. So i downloaded the source, updated cmake to the required version, installed gcc 9 and tried to compile it using cmake. I did not succeed using the CMakeLists.txt in the root directory, but i succeeded in building the lib using the CMakeLists.txt in the core directory. The result was a libZXing.a, which i installed using the make install target. The lib was installed into /usr/local/lib. So far so good.
Now i try to build a very simple program, just to test, if building was successful.

```
#include "BarcodeFormat.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace ZXing;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, BarcodeFormat bf) {
    os << ToString(bf);
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (auto f : BarcodeFormats::all()) {
        std::cout << f << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling works, linking does not work: Undefined reference to BarcodeFormat::ToString(BarcodeFormat). So it seems to be not in the library. I compiled the BarcodeFormat.cpp in the core/src directory separately, copied the object file to my project directory, linked it, and that worked. I got a working executable.

So i assume i did something wrong while building the library. Any idea what could go wrong here? Of cource i added the necessary -I, -L and -l flags to the compile. The Makefile:

```
CC      := g++
CCFLAGS     := -std=c++17 -I/home/cnc/prj/zxing-cpp-master/core/src 
LDFLAGS     := -L/usr/local/lib -lZXing

all:        zxtest

zxtest:     zxtest.o BarcodeFormat.o
            ${CC} -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} $^

zxtest.o:   zxtest.cpp
            ${CC} -c ${CCFLAGS} -o $@ $<

BarcodeFormat.o:    ../zxing-cpp-master/core/src/BarcodeFormat.cpp
            ${CC} -c ${CCFLAGS} -o $@ $<
```

Without that extra BarcodeFormat file it does not link

I'm quite old, so i do know C and basic C++. I'm not up to date with the new C++ features.

PS: Sorry, i forgot: This is about the ZXing c++ port (obviously, since the example is c++): https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp

Comment: _"Any idea what could go wrong here?"_ Many different things could go wrong there and it's nearly impossible to help without a [mcve].

Comment: What kind of example do you need? I changed into the core directory and typed "cmake .", then make, then make install. That created the lib, as described above. Now i try to compile an example. The example is in the question. Additionally the Makefile is in the question, so there are all c++ and linker flags i used. I use "make all" to build this. That's standard. So what kind of minimal reproduciblw example do you need? I have no idea.

Comment: _"I did not succeed using the CMakeLists.txt in the root directory,"_ As far as I understand this question you have a problem with CMake but there is no CMake code in your question. You didn't provide all necessary files to test the Makefile.

Comment: The CMakeList.txt files are downloaded with the library code. They are part of ZXing. They are quite lengthy. Should i nevertheless post them here?

Comment: If I have a problem with my car and I show you my bike, can you fix the problem with my car? _"Should i nevertheless post them here?"_ No, create a [mcve] with focus on minimal, the smallest possible but complete project that reproduces your problem. Some people possibly want to recreate your situation on their computers and they don't want to visit external web sites for this.

Comment: I did this. The c++ source code is in the question. The Makefile i used to compile this is in the question. This is a minimal reproducible example. Prerequisite for this example is the ZXing library. And jus to make it explicitely clear: The question has nothing to do with cmake. I did not use cmake to build this Makefile. I made it by hand. But to reproduce it it is obviously necessary to visit an external web site to download and build the ZXing library. This is not necessary if you already have the library. If you don't have it and don't want to install it, forget it.

Comment: _"But to reproduce it it is obviously necessary to visit an external web site to download and build the ZXing library."_ In that case this question is off-topic for this platform. Questions have to be self-contained. If this is a problem with ZXing library you probably should ask the developers of that library or [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues)

Comment: I don't know if this is a problem of the ZXing library or if i did sonething wrong. That is part of the question. If such questions are off-topic here, well...

Comment: No, this kind of questions are not off-topic here but questions that doesn't contain effort to analyze the problem: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and questions without [mcve]. Stackoverflow is a Q6A platform with the goal to help future users with similar problems but this question will become worthless if the external resource gets invalid. Locate the problem. Find out why the build fails. Reproduce it. Provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else trying to make ZXing C++ work on Linux, the following worked for me (Ubuntu 20+). You don't need to install any packages to make it work, as GCC was already installed on my version of Ubuntu, but YMMW.

I am using the [following](https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp) ZXing fork. It's a C++ port from the original Java. Seems to be the most up to date version I can find. I tried using the Java also, but the C++ version is faster, and a little bit less faffy to get working.

Ok, enough context, let's get straight to it.

#### Prep it

You'll need to install `git` and `cmake`.

```
sudo apt install git cmake
```

#### Clone it

Clone a copy of the page and make the folder we want build the package in

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp.git
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/zxing-cpp/
```

#### Build it

Build the package in the folder we made, go to the folder and install the package.

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -G "Unix Makefiles" -S zxing-cpp/ -B /usr/lib/zxing-cpp/
cd /usr/lib/zxing-cpp/
sudo make install
```

A quick note, I got a bunch of `depreciated` warnings when I ran the `sudo make install` command. It still works though.

#### Use it

Now here' the bit that confused me a little. I was not able to just call `ZXing` from the command line as you might expect when you apt-install something.

I had to find the `ZXingReader` file (I was only interested in reading images, you can also create barcodes with the same package) that was created in the `/usr/lib/zxing-cpp/example/` folder and reference it directly. Then I could call it directly from the command line like so

```
/usr/lib/zxing-cpp/example/ZXingReader image.jpg
```

This should give you the following result, if it finds a barcode.

```
Text:     "5901234123457"
Format:   EAN-13
Position: 81x363 1176x363 1176x363 81x363
Rotation: 0 deg
Error:    NoError
Country:  PL
```

Hope that helps. And, please, if you are a Linux expert, let me know in the comments where I am going wrong, or where I could be doing things in a more efficient manner. Compiling C++ programmes is very much on the periphery of my comfort zone!

Answer (score 0):

At least we got it here working in some way. Instead of using the hand made Makefile, a collegue gave me a cmake input file:

```
project(zxtest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable (zxtest zxtest.cpp)

include_directories(/usr/local/include/ZXing)

target_link_libraries (zxtest ZXing)
```

Then we created the Makefile using cmake and this input file. The resulting Makefile is over 5K big. But that works. We still do not know *why* resp. why it does not work with the hand made Makefile.
So the bug is somehow in the Makefile provided in the question above.